# Prove $\min(x,y,z) \leq ax+by+cz \leq \max(x,y,z), $ with $a+b+c = 1$

Tags: analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

How to prove this lemma?

> $\min(x,y,z) \leq ax+by+cz \leq \max(x,y,z)$, with  $a+b+c = 1$ for any real numbers $x,y,z$ and $a,b,c$ positive.

Comment: Prove $(a+b+c)\min(x,y,z) \leq ax+by+cz \leq (a+b+c) \max(x,y,z)$ for any $a,b,c \geq 0$ (Hint: compare term by term)

Comment: is it sufficient to say : $a \min(x,y,z)+b \min(x,y,z)+c \min(x,y,z) \leq ax+by+cz \leq a \max(x,y,z)+b \max(x,y,z)+c \max(x,y,z)$ so factorising by min and max because a+b+c= 1 and conclude ?

Comment: Yes, that's enough. Might you or @Lelouch want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Proof with geometric flavour:

Consider $ax+by+cz$ as a **barycentric combination** of points $x,y,z$ with positive coefficients $a,b,c$ whose sum is $1$. The result is necessarily between the two extreme points, i.e., $\min(x,y,z)$ and $\max(x,y,z)$.

(one could have also used a **convexity** argumentation).

Answer (score 0):

$a \min(x,y,z)+b \min(x,y,z)+c \min(x,y,z) \leq ax+by+cz \leq a \max(x,y,z)+b \max(x,y,z)+c \max(x,y,z)$